# Extending the application session token time by configuring Sign-in frequency in Azure AD Condition Access Policy doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-policy

We have tried extending the session token time of an openid application on-boarded in Azure AD by configuring Sign-in frequency in Azure AD Condition Access Policy as suggested in the below MS document -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime

But it doesn't prompt for re-authentication after the configured sign-in frequency time period expires.
We have on-boarded **ClickHelp** app & set the sign-in frequency for 1 hour.

Need help with the configuration in Azure AD to extend the oAuth app session token time by 8hrs (application session should get expire after 8hrs & prompt to re-authenticate with Azure AD)

Also, wanted to know if conditional access policy only works with Microsoft apps?
Because when I configured policy for all cloud apps with sign-in-frequency set to 1hr, and hit the URL "https://endpoint.microsoft.com" in browser. I received the following error message on refreshing the URL after 1 hr -
[Conditional access policy failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip9Pd.png)

{
"sessionId": "1026a56be9a04d77xxxxxx",
"missingClaims": "{"access_token":{"capolids":{"essential":true,"values":["83b40f65-1d01-45cc-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"]}}}",
"resourceName": "graph",
"errorMessage": "AADSTS70043: The refresh token has expired or is invalid due to sign-in frequency checks by conditional access. The token was issued on 2020-09-15T11:26:21.5620000Z and the maximum allowed lifetime for this request is 3600.\r\nTrace ID: 2933c79c-e69b-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx\r\nCorrelation ID: aab286b8-ea79-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx\r\nTimestamp: 2020-09-15 12:50:22Z"
}

Comment: Please let us know which type of application you are using? The sign-in frequency setting works with apps that have implemented OAUTH2 or OIDC protocols according to the standards

Comment: Hi Sruthi, We're using OIDC supported app

Comment: Does conditional access policy only works with MS apps? Because when I configured policy for all cloud apps & hit the URL "https://endpoint.microsoft.com" in browser. I received following error msg after 1 hr on refreshing the URL. Conditional access policy failure-
Your Azure AD Tenant admin has enabled conditional access policies. You will need to sign in again to access your resources.
 "AADSTS70043: The refresh token has expired or is invalid due to sign-in frequency checks by conditional access. The token was issued on <Date> & the maximum allowed lifetime for this request is 3600."

Comment: Please let us know which  authentication library you are using like msal or Adal

Comment: It's not our custom created OIDC app. We're testing with publicly available trial version OIDC supported app. We just did configuration at AZ AD end & app end to enable sso.
 App name : clickhelp (https://clickhelp.com/)
 For authentication & authorization, app is sending the request to Auth URL(OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint (v1)) : https://login.microsoftonline.com/<AZADtenantID>/oauth2/authorize

Comment: Please provide correlation id and timestamp

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question

Comment: No Sruthi, Thanks.